# How to match strings of only a specific length of characters in regex? (Python)

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-group

I'm using

```
\[(.*?)\]|Response code (?P<code>\d+)
```

to search these fields:

```
[2018-01-20 05:19:54.812] INFO    com.mulesoft.ch.monitoring.MonitoringCoreExtension [qtp689806602-32]: Monitoring enabled: true
[2018-01-20 05:19:54.813] INFO    com.mulesoft.ch.monitoring.MonitoringCoreExtension [qtp689806602-32]: Registering ping flow injector...
[2018-01-20 05:19:54.833] INFO    com.mulesoft.ch.queue.boot.PersistentQueueCoreExtension [qtp689806602-32]: The PersistentQueueManager is NOT configured. The normal VM queue manager will be used.
[2018-01-20 05:19:54.841] INFO    org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager [qtp689806602-32]: Initialising RegistryBroker
[2018-01-20 05:19:54.872] INFO
[2018-01-24 02:14:30.153] INFO    org.mule.routing.SynchronousUntilSuccessfulProcessingStrategy [[swt-fastsalescomp-anaplan-schedules].ScatterGatherWorkManager.24]: Exception thrown inside until-successful org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException: Response code 503 mapped as failure.
```

But I only want it to match the dates, not the other stuff that's between brackets as well as assign a named group 'code'(that parts working). I tried several variations including

```
\[(\d*?)\]
\[(\W*?)\]
\[^(\.*?){23}$\]
```

But I can't seem to get it to find anything with those criteria.

Bonus:
I might be able to figure this one out once the rest is solved, but I might as well ask while I'm in here. How do I update a dictionary with the date and code as a key value pair?

Comment: Only dates, not the time?

Comment: See [this approach](https://regex101.com/r/HKWPhK/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you can add a `^` for the first part of your regex to impose that it starts at the beginning of the line for the timestamp!!! otherwise great as usual ;-)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex**: [`\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2}[^]]+|(?<=Response code )(?P<code>\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/bfozek/2)

Details:

- `(?:)` Non-capturing group
- `{n}` Matches exactly `n` times
- `[^]` Named Capture Group
- `|` Or
- `(?<=)` Positive Lookbehind
- `(?P<>)` Named Capture Group

**Python code**:

```
for match in re.finditer(r'\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2}[^]]+|(?<=Response code )(?P<code>\d+)', text):
    print(match.group())
```

**Output**:

```
2018-01-20 05:19:54.812
2018-01-20 05:19:54.813
2018-01-20 05:19:54.833
2018-01-20 05:19:54.841
2018-01-20 05:19:54.872
2018-01-24 02:14:30.153
503
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/hBJ8iV)

Comment: As a followup, how would I only return time values that have a 503 with them?

Comment: @Cdhippen You mean 02:14:30.153?

Comment: Yes. My log has literal thousands of time entries, I'm trying to pull out only lines with time and a status code.

Comment: changed it to this: https://pastebin.com/9wNsiU6u and now I have exactly what I want (I don't need the milliseconds, that will just complicate things since I'm going to try and put it in matplotlib) Thanks a ton for the help!